# What if I don't feel comfortable sharing my source code?

Tags: discussion

What if I don't feel comfortable sharing my source code? Like if there is private info.

Comment: Remove the private info. Or write another version that is safe and only has the relevant parts for where you’re stuck.

Comment: Replace the private info with generic data

Comment: Replace the private info with dummy data or come up with a different example that has the same problem. If neither of those are possible, you may be out of luck - people can't answer your question if you can't provide sufficient details.

Comment: If there's bits of private data in it, redact it and replace it with fake data or clear it entirely (in the case of strings, you can also leave blank strings). If you consider your entire source code private, you'll need to find somewhere else to ask

Comment: You should be cutting your code down to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example anyway; we can't help you with code we can't see.

Comment: For big text exists lore ipsum and the rest you must edit it. it doesn't matter if John doe or harry potter stands for name or even test1 test2 test3, numbers usually doesn't ,atter ithere is only one number or 10....

Comment: don't use a *public* website ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  That is an oversimplification.  You can use a public website as long as *private* information isn't published on it.

Comment: What are you able to propose towards answering this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you can't share your code, chances are *very* high that we can't really help you out.

It's fine to have code that's sensitive; you should ask for explicit permission to ask a question related to it.  If you can, redact the sensitive parts of your code such that your team is comfortable with it being shared, or attempt to replicate the actual problem you're having in a vanilla, clean-room fashion.

From my perspective, you not wanting to share code is like calling emergency dispatch without being specific as to what's going on or what address you're calling from.

Answer (score 13):

The actual problem that you're asking about is almost always logically orthogonal to any private data that you may have, and so it is simply a matter of extracting one from the other, allowing you to expose the problem in a general but understandable and possibly reproducible way. If you are not able to do this, then likely we can't help you.